# Unable to pass intent extras from Activity to fragment inside Viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm using `ViewPager` and a `TabLayout` to show two fragments. I'm getting an URL as an intent extra from the previous activity and passing them as an argument from current activity to the fragment. But inside the fragment, I'm not getting any `Bundle` and when using toast message in the fragment, it shows null.

Here is my code for `MainActivity`

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

String url_one = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);

// I'm getting this Toast as url sucessfully
Toast.makeText(this, url_one, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Mylecture f = new Mylecture();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("key_one", url_one);
f.setArguments(args);

adapter.addFragment(new Mylecture(), "Lectures");

viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

And inside the fragment, I'm using

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
if(bundle != null) {
    url = bundle.getString("key_one");
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bundle is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This returns the `Bundle` is empty.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are adding fragments in your `ViewPager`, you are actually not passing the fragment where you have put the bundle and that's why you are not getting anything in your fragment.

You need to do the following.

```
Mylecture f = new Mylecture();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("key_one", url_one);
f.setArguments(args);

// adapter.addFragment(new Mylecture(), "Lectures"); // Do not new a fragment
adapter.addFragment(f, "Lectures"); // Use this instead
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great to know that helped!